# Test different timezones

Tags: html, javascript, internationalization

What is a simple way to temporarily change the timezone in Chrome so as to test how a site renders for different locations?

On OSX Mountain Lion, I've tried as bash script with:

```
export TZ='Indian/Mauritius'

date
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app ~/status.html
```

where status.html * contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Time zone test</title>
</head>
<div id="local"></div>
<div id="offset"></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('local').innerHTML = "The local time is " + (new Date()).toLocaleString();
    document.getElementById('offset').innerHTML = "Local offset:" + (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

The **date** command correctly returns Mauritius time, but the javascript renders the time as being my machine's time

* apologies for posting the *whole* file, but there might be relevant tags I haven't considered

Answer (score 1):

Turns out one needs to kill all existing Chrome processes first.

```
export TZ='Indian/Mauritius'

killall Chrome
date
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app ~/status.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest method would be just to change the time on your local machine, I'm sure you know how to do this already but: [OS X Mountain Lion: Date & Time preferences](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10638).